# Access html control from server side .aspx.cs

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a table with a tbody in my aspx with the id fileslist, I need to inject the tr td from the server, the problem is that at runtime aspx changes the name of the id to ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fileslist, this is my code

```
var html = "";

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            html += $"<tr>" +
                        $"<td class='row_files'>{item.NAME_DOC}</td>" +
                        $"<td class='row_files'><button class='btn-delete-file' type='button'>Delete</button></td>" +
                    $"</tr>";
        }

        fileslist.InnerHtml = html;
```

aspx add ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fileslist to the id, How can i solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is default behavior of the framework that all ID's of serverside controls are made unique when rendered. You can override this behavior by adding:

```
<table id="fileslist" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ... >
```

Of course you have to make sure yourself then, that no two controls have the same ID.